# How to install fail2ban using ansible?

Tags: ansible, fail2ban

I want to use install fail2ban across a range of servers using ansible, ansible is already installed and set up (someone else done this) but my main problem is trying to understand how to create a playbook (which if I'm correct will install fail2ban across the range of servers).

Oh I am also using the jail.conf file from a previous machine which I installed fail2ban on manually as I want the configuration (such as time to ban people, who's on the whitelist etc) to be the same across all the servers!

This is my first ever post so if I've forgotten anything please be gentle!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm assuming Ubuntu/Debian here but you can alter this for other OSes.

```
$ cat roles/fail2ban/tasks/main.yml
- name: install fail2ban package
  apt: pkg=fail2ban state=present
  when: ansible_distribution=='Debian' or ansible_distribution=='Ubuntu'
  sudo: yes
- name: copy fail2ban local config
  file: src=jail.local dest=/etc/fail2ban/jail.local owner=root group=root mode=0644
  sudo: yes

$ cat roles/fail2ban/files/jail.local
# put your config here
```

Comment: Ok thanks! I've done some research and I think have to create a group of hosts and call them within the playbook e.g - hosts: webservers don't I? Also regarding the '# put your config here' I might sound stupid but i'm assuming I can just copy and paste the contents of the entire config file in this part?

Comment: @TobyApplegate yes and yes.

Comment: `file` or `copy`?